# Как записать даты range datapicker в 2 инпута?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

Нужно реализовать такой календарь, использую плагин http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index-ru.html датапикера, но не могу понять как записать даты в два инпута? подскажите плиз

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Представляю вам два варианта

---

**Вариант первый :**

```js
$('#start_one').datepicker({ 
  onSelect: function (fd, d, picker) { 
    $("#start_one").val(fd.split("-")[0]);
    $("#end_one").val(fd.split("-")[1]);
  }
});
```

```css
.one {
  width:100%;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Date</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css" />

</head>
<body>

  <div class="one">
    <label for="start_one">С:</label>
    <input type="text" id="start_one" data-range="true" data-multiple-dates-separator=" - " class="datepicker-here"/>
    <label for="start_one">До:</label>
    <input type='text' id='end_one'>
  </div>
 

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/i18n/datepicker.en.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Вариант второй :**

```js
var $start = $('#start'),
$end = $('#end');

$start.datepicker({
  onSelect: function (fd, date) {
    $end.data('datepicker')
    .update('minDate', date);

    $end.focus();
  }
})
$end.datepicker({
  onSelect: function (fd, date) {
    $start.data('datepicker')
    .update('maxDate', date)
  }
})
```

```css
.two{
  width:100%;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Date</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css" />

</head>
<body>
 
  <div class="two">
    <label for="start">С:</label>
     <input type='text' id='start'>
    <label for="end">До:</label>
     <input type='text' id='end'>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/i18n/datepicker.en.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```